# Tensorflow neural network regression with binary constraints

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, regression, softmax

I have coded a simple softmax regression neural net in tensorflow with 6 features and 6 targets. However, I would like to impose a somewhat binary type constraint on two of the targets such that when it finds one the other is forced to zero. That is, if targets are y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6 then as an example when there is value for y3, y4=0 and vice versa. Note this is explicit on the training data but I just want to make sure the network captures this efficiently as it is a hard constraint. Is that possible? Or do we expect the network to learn this constraint?

Comment: Does that mean you decode the two output nodes always as [0 1] or [1 0] in your training data?

Comment: Yes. But it is a regression so the actual values for either of those, when 1, can be anything as I am sure you figured.

Comment: Have you considered to merge those two nodes into a single one? E.g. if one is below 0.5 it is class A and otherwise it is class B. This way you would make them implicitly mutually exclusive.

Comment: I am not sure that would work (or maybe I dont understand) becuase it is a softmax regression for all the six targets simultaneously which means the probability can be anything between 0 and 1 and we cannot set a 0.5 threshold.